# Invoking particular action on dropdown list selection in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp-net-mvc-1

I have a dropdown list in an MVC view. On selection change of dropdown list I want to call specific action method in the controller.

What I have done on view is this :

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("ddl", ViewData["AvailableList"] as SelectList,
  new { onchange = "this.form.action='MyMethod';this.form.submit();" })%>
```

Everything is getting compiled. But a runtime exception is thrown when I change the drop down selection, as

> "Microsift JScript Runtime Error : Object doesn't support property or method"

How can I redirect to specific action on list selection change event?
How can I pass parameters to this action method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your approach should work.  The issue you're encountering is your use of `this` in your `onchange` event is invalid. Try replacing your `this.form` references with something like this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
        "ddl", ViewData["AvailableList"] as SelectList, 
        new { onchange = @"
            var form = document.forms[0]; 
            form.action='MyMethod';
            form.submit();" 
        } ) %>
```

Comment: what does %= mean here? I can't remember

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet: It's for outputting HTML to the page. Here's a good reference for all those tags: https://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags

Answer (score 23):

Do you really need to submit the form? You could redirect:

```
onchange = "redirect(this.value)"
```

where `redirect` is a custom defined function:

```
function redirect(dropDownValue) {
    window.location.href = '/myController/myAction/' + dropDownValue;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it only works if I pass the parameter as a query string, for example: window.location.href = '/myController/myAction?param=' + dropDownValue;

Comment: @fjxx, you should be able to fix this by reconfiguring your [URL routing](http://goo.gl/fKcxX).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, is there a way to do this as a one-liner, without defining the function in js?

Comment: @Shimmy, yes there's a way: `onchange = "window.location.href='/myController/myAction/' + this.value;"`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov and what if I want to use `Url.Action`, is there still a way to include the `this.value` from JS in the route values anonym. object (I know I can do this manually `?query=value`, but I prefer `Url.Action`)?

Comment: @Shimmy, no there's no way. `Url.Action` runs on the server whereas `this.value` is known only on the client. The proper way to do this is to put this dropdown inside an HTML form with a submit button so that you don't need to use javascript to manually craft urls.

Comment: awesome! <script>
                function redirect(dropDownValue)
                    {
                    window.location.href = '/@myController.ControllerName?pagesize=' + dropDownValue;
                    }
            </script>
            @Html.DropDownList("pagesize", ViewData["listPageSizes"] as SelectList,
                new
                {
                    Class = "form-control",
                    onchange = "redirect(this.value)"
                })

Answer (score 6):

This is a jQuery thing. Give it a class and wire up to it.

```
Html.DropDownList("ddl", AvailableList, new { @class = "_select_change" })
```

A rough script might look like this:

```
$('._select_change').change(function() { $.post(ctrlUrl); })
```

Answer (score 2):

Like both : D

I propose a mix -I like a lot the jQuery.

```
$('ddl').change(
 function() {
  // This contains your selected option val
  $(this).val();

// so you can do domething like...
  $.post(
    $(this).val(),
    { Param1: xxxx,
      Param2: xxxx,
      Param3: xxxx },
    function(data) {
     // handle your call here. 'data' contains the response
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the controller action, you're going to make the call the same way:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(ddl, ViewData["items"] as SelectList, new { onchange = string.format("doSomething({0}); return false;", action) }) %>
```

Once you do that, put a Javascript function on your page that calls the method.  How you call it, however, is going to depend on whether it's an AJAX call or not.  That is, whether you want a page round-trip or not.  For the non-AJAX call:

```
function doSomething(action) {
    window.location.href = action;
}
```

If it's an AJAX call:

```
function doSomething(action) {
    $.load(action);
}
```

To pass parameters to the action, you just need to make sure that all of the data elements you want to pass are contained within the `<form>` tag.  For example, let's say you want to include a first and last name with your drop down list.  In the view, you'll do something like this:

```
<%= using (Html.BeginForm()) 
   { %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><%= Html.TextBox("FirstName") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><%= Html.TextBox("LastName") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Assign to:</td>
            <td><%= Html.DropDownList(ddl, ViewData["items"] as SelectList, 
                new { onchange = string.format("doSomething({0}); return false;", ViewData["action"]) }) %></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
<% } %>
```

In the Javascript function:

```
function doSomething(action) {
    var firstName = $('#FirstName').val();
    var lastName = $('#LastName').val();
    $.load(action, { first: firstName, last: lastName });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> @Shimmy  is there a way to do this as a one-liner, without defining
>   the function in js?

yes you can and here is the code for that:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.DropDownName, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/Employee?c=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StudentId, new SelectList(ViewBag.List, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:65px", onchange = "document.location.href = '/Student/find?Id=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could also explain your code

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you answer a question you should include some kind of explanation, like what the author did wrong and what you did to fix it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged as low-quality and is currently being reviewed. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the "Edit" button.

Comment: I concur with Nick Kahn's solution. I pasted my own working code as confirmation.